# Doctrine: addSelect method creates undesired seperate object (Symfony)

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I want to query the entity based on a calculated property that does not exist in the database or on the entity.

If I run

```
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('b')
            ->addSelect(
                '... as extra_property'
            )
            ->having('extra_property = :param')
            ->setParameter('param', $param)
            ->orderBy('extra_property', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

This results in a collection with each entity in the following format:

```
"0": {}, // The 9 entity properties
"extra_property": "value"
```

However, I want the extra_property to be added to the other entity properties as the tenth property. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the getResult() method, the default hydration method is "HYDRATE_OBJECT" which will try to hydrate the output as the defined entity, which does not know about your extra property.

```
public function getResult($hydrationMode = self::HYDRATE_OBJECT)
{
    return $this->execute(null, $hydrationMode);
}
```

Depending on what your other properties are, you could just use the "HYDRATE_SCALAR" option which will just give you a flat output of the results.

If you other properties are nested entities, you will have to manually select the fields in your select to bypass the hydration process, or find a way to add that property to your entity and tell the hydrator to get that data from a dedicated query or something.

You can find the different hydration methods as constants of the AbstractQuery class, you can read more on the [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats)

```
/**
 * Hydrates an object graph. This is the default behavior.
 */
public const HYDRATE_OBJECT = 1;

/**
 * Hydrates an array graph.
 */
public const HYDRATE_ARRAY = 2;

/**
 * Hydrates a flat, rectangular result set with scalar values.
 */
public const HYDRATE_SCALAR = 3;

/**
 * Hydrates a single scalar value.
 */
public const HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR = 4;

/**
 * Very simple object hydrator (optimized for performance).
 */
public const HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT = 5;

/**
 * Hydrates scalar column value.
 */
public const HYDRATE_SCALAR_COLUMN = 6;
```